# How to define conditional property in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I'd like define a conditional property in pom.xml based on another property. 
e.g. property p1=value1 when feature1.enabled=true and p1=value2 when feature1.enabled=false

```
  mvn compile -Dfeature1.enabled=true
```

Comment: Have you read about maven profiles, with command line for example `-PrunIntegrationTests`

Answer (score 4):

You could try using Maven build profiles, something like:

```xml
<profiles> 
    <profile>
        <id>feature1-enabled</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>feature1.enabled</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <p1>value1</p1>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>feature1-disabled</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>feature1.enabled</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <p1>value2</p1>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Usage:

```
mvn compile -Dfeature1.enabled=true
```

Comment: Doing this means that you will always have an "active" profile....which in turn means that all your other "active-by-default" profiles will need to be specifically activated....which can make people crazy.